# python hex-editor binary change

Tags: python, editor, binaryfiles

i want to change binary value in file in

elif(IN = edithex)

//
this part have problem....

open.write(b'\xff') << this code is working but i want to use (input data) to (write)

help me..

```
inedit = raw_input("change hex value >")
OPEN.write(b'\xff')





    elif (IN == 'edithex'):
        editoffset = int(offset, 0)
        OPEN.seek(editoffset)
        inedit = raw_input("change hex value >")
        OPEN.write(b'\xff')
        print ('hex value changed ==>' + inedit)
```

Comment: Please show complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print the binary data equivalent to the hexadecimal code provided by user. That would be:

```
OPEN.write(chr(int(inedit, base=16)))
```

Here `int()` is used to convert the hexadecimal number provided by user to integer, and `chr()` is used to convert that into the binary character.

As an exercise, you need to handle possible `ValueError`s when user types in an invalid value :).